Meaning of יוֹצֵר בְּרֵאשִׁית
What is the meaning and kavana for יוֹצֵר בְּרֵאשִׁית - "Maker of Bereshit" - eg. in מודים דרבנן and עלינו לשבח
? Especially, in light of the point made by Ramban in Bereshit 1:1 where the word יצר is contrasted with ברא, with the latter being more appropriate for describing how Hashem "made" the beginning? The beginning wasn't "formed" (יצר) but "created from nothing" (ברא).
Is it perhaps similar to עוֹשֶׂה בְרֵאשִׁית in e.g. ברוך שאמר, which I always understood has having an inferred "מַעֲשֵׂה" in between, i.e. עוֹשֶׂה מַעֲשֵׂה
בְרֵאשִׁית, which is referring to a well understood concept מַעֲשֵׂה בְרֵאשִׁית - "The Act of Creation", e.g. Bereshit 2:1-3: כִּי בוֹ שָׁבַת מִכָּל־מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר־בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים לַעֲשׂוֹת, etc.

Could the translation be " the creator at the beginning"

@rosends Never heard that perush. Probably that would be היוצר בָּראשית, but that's already opening another can of worms - בָּ, not  בְּ, "in the beginning of" etc

Yerushalmi Berakhot 1:5 and Bavli Sotah 40a both describe the origins of Modim DeRabanan and attribute the provenance of the phrase to R. Simai. Interestingly, Bavli (which lists half a dozen short sayings which were then collected into our version of MDR) has “yotzrenu yotzer bereshit” implying that “yozter” was meant to parallel “yotzrenu”, which is fitting because that’s the verb the Torah uses to describe the creation of humanity in Bereshit 2. However, Yerushalmi (which lists many longer versions of MDR) does not have “yotzrenu”. Make of that what you will.

IIRC, Philo or Josephus were the first to coin the term בראשית as "creation" to start with. Also, I remember a paper that showed that due to the huge linguistic variety of Jewish sources, there's no terminological consistency in any of them: Torah, Nakh, or Rabbinic literature. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143574/three-different-things-created-by-briah-heavens-and-earth-dinosaurs-water-cre
